# Get access to variable from previous pageview, excluding ajax-calls

Tags: php, hooks, variables

I want to generate a random string, and get it passed to the next pageview.

I currently have the following code:

```
  add_action('init', 'set_global_pixelcapival');
  function set_global_pixelcapival() {

      global $pixelcapival;
      $pixelcapival = pixelcapival();

      global $prev_pixelcapival;
      $prev_pixelcapival = '';

      if(isset($_COOKIE['pixelcapival'])) {
         $prev_pixelcapival = $_COOKIE['pixelcapival'];
      }

      setcookie('pixelcapival', $pixelcapival, time() + 1200, '/');
 }
```

I can now get access to $pixelcapival from the previous pageview by

```
global $prev_pixelcapival
```

But if any ajax-calls are being made in between, i guess the ajax-call triggers the init-action, and i don´t get the value i want.
(The ajax-call is in this case made by a plugin, when clicking a submit-button)

Is there any easy way to prevent this? A hook that isn´t triggered by ajax calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out you could identify ajax requests by the following if-statement

```
if (defined('DOING_AJAX') && DOING_AJAX)
```

So problem solved using

```
add_action('init', 'set_global_pixelcapival');
function set_global_pixelcapival() {
  if (defined('DOING_AJAX') && DOING_AJAX) { 
    
  } else {
    global $pixelcapival;
    $pixelcapival = pixelcapival();

    global $prev_pixelcapival;
    $prev_pixelcapival = '';

    if(isset($_COOKIE['pixelcapival'])) {
        $prev_pixelcapival = $_COOKIE['pixelcapival'];
    }
    setcookie('pixelcapival', $pixelcapival, time() + 1200, '/');
  }
}
```